# Write an add-on or greasemonkey script to "Ajaxify" webpages in Firefox?

Tags: ajax, firefox, firefox-addon, greasemonkey

I stumbled upon this add-on which "Ajaxifies" parts of its target website.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/51789

I have a similar need like this. I want only part of the webpage's DOM to update upon receiving click on a link, since the website has a rather unified page layout.

I have no experiences in writing FF add-ons but I did some basic Ajax and DOM before. So I am looking for programming tips on how to implement "Ajaxification" in a GreaseMonkey script, preferably. If it's not possible, making an add-on is also a sound choice which I'm willing to learn.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that's the link to the right add-on?

Comment: If it does what I think it does (Ajax instead of refresh the whole page), then yes this is an example.

Comment: Why not build this into your site rather than making it a browser-specific addon?

Comment: It would be mainly for enhancing third party sites. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`GM_xmlhttpRequest`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest) allows GreaseMonkey to do an XMLHttpRequest (to whereever).  You can then load the results in the DOM as normal.

Comment: Thanks. This looks rather promising.